Reads numbers until "Stop" and prints the largest
Please I need help for this exercise.
"Write a program that, until the "Stop" command is received, reads integers entered by the user, finds the largest among them, and prints it. Enter one number per line."
Input:
45
-20
7
99
Stop

Expected output:
99

Tried:
import sys

biggest_number = -sys.maxsize

while True:
    number = input()
    if number == "Stop":
        break
    number = int(number)
    if biggest_number > number:
        biggest_number = number

print(biggest_number)


Type error missing if-else  number > biggest_number:

number = int(input()) If you call int() right away, the user can never enter "Stop".

@dstv I have updated my answer to include explanation for every line of code, and also to ignore the '-' prefix, such that the command '-STOP' works as well as 'stop'

Try this:
biggest_number = None

while True:
    n = input("Write a number:")
    if n == "Stop":
        break
    if n.isnumeric():
        if biggest_number is None or int(n) > biggest_number:
            biggest_number = int(n)

print(biggest_number)


Note that your code doesn't work since you forgot ':'

Yes, sorry, you are right

how do you stop the program?, find out the biggest number?

You stop it when you enter "Stop" instead of the number

And the biggest number is being searched continuously, when you input a number and it is bigger than the current biggest one, the biggest_number is rewritten to the new value

You can do this as follows:
def readNum(NUM):
 num = input("Enter Number: ")#request user input
 if len(num)>2 and num[0] == "-" and not num[1].isnumeric():
    num= num[1:]#remove the '-' if present
 else:
    if len(num)>1 and num[0] == '-' and num[1].isnumeric():
     return -int(num[1:])
 if num.isnumeric():
    return int(num)#is a number

 elif num.lower() == "stop":#check if user wants to quit
    exit(f"Process stopped, biggest number: {NUM}")#Cancel the Process if user wants to quit
 else:
    print(f"Error: {num} is not a number. Please try again")#Report to the user that what they have entered is not a number
    return readNum(NUM)#Repeat the process till the user enters a number

biggestNumber = readNum("None")#Get first number
while True:#start loop
 newNum = readNum(biggestNumber)
 if newNum>biggestNumber: biggestNumber=newNum#check if number is bigger than the biggest one so far, if so change the biggest number to the present one

This reads the number the user entered and if the user enter for example a string he prompted again

Need to work also with negative number like this input : " -1
-2
Stop" expected output is "-1"

@dstv everything is working now as you want

Failed with this input:
45
-20
7
99
Stop

Nice ! But now failed with input:                                                                              -10
20
-30
Stop     expected output should be 20

@dstv Should work

Nice, the result is correct {20} , but how to print just 20 , without the curly brackets {}

@dstv many ways for example: exit("result:  %s"%(biggestNumber)) or exit("result:"+str(biggestNumber)), just to name a few
